# Only allow user access to Window Desktop on RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, window

Just wonder is there a way to only allow user access to the window desktop of a RDP session.
Which mean user can only execute any file and app on the desktop, but cannot double click into the computer , c drive or d drive

Thanks

Comment: You could possibly set up something similar with permissions? So, when the user logs on, they are under a certain group and the policy limits their actions

Comment: Group Policy can do a whole lot of things in regards to restricting access. So you can have that user in a certain group, and windows, once knowing the user is in that certain group, will allow RDP, but at the same time apply the group policy with the restrictions. By default User (non admin) can still access the root drive (C: and/or D:) but with no write access to them. They can only write to their ?:/Users/username.

Comment: thank you for the comment, i think group policy work for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

With group policy settings you can certainly block the access to almost anything. The question is, will the app the user tries to run still work.

You may wan't to try [RemoteApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx) instead. In this way the users access is redirected to the application and maybe some files and folders which he really needs.

Comment: Hi Daniel, i think i will try on the group policy, if dont meet my requirement, then will try again on the remote app, thank you so much, appreciate.